# How to make to_csv into controller with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-csv

First of all, I received the task

1. Add Export button above user list table
2. Clicking the button should download a
   CSV file with user fields displayed on
   the page

app/controllers/admins/users_controller.rb

```
def index
   @users = User.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv(['email']) }
   end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
 def self.to_csv(fields = column_names, options = {})
 CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
   csv << fields
   all.each do |user|
     csv << user.attributes.values_at(*fields)
   end
 end
```

end

app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag import_admins_users_path, multipart: true, class: 'form-inline' do %>
     <div class="form-group">
       <%= link_to "Export CSV", admins_users_path(format: "csv"), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
namespace :admins do
 resources :users do
   collection { post :import }
 end
```

end

Method **to_csv** should not be in the model

How to leave it in the **controller**??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question -- "The `to_csv` method be in the controller, not the model"? Why? Is something about your current implementation not working? It looks like you've successfully solved the original task?

Comment: It doesn't look like the `to_csv` method really belongs in the controller, and it's not really a model method either. IMO it should either be a view (given that its job appears to be formatting and delivering data) or a plain ruby object.

Answer (score 3):

The CSV generation method arguably should not be in the controller either as it will be hard to test in isolation. Fat controllers are a known anti-pattern.

Instead create a seperate object that takes the users and serializes it as CSV:

```
class UsersCSVGenerator

  def initialize(users, fields:, **options)
    @users = users
    @options = options
    @fields = fields
  end

  def call
    CSV.generate(**@options) do |csv|
      csv << fields
      @users.each do |user|
        csv << user.attributes.values_at(*@fields)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.call(users, fields: User.column_names, **options)
    new(users, fields: fields, **options).call
  end
end
```

This is basically the [Service Object pattern](https://medium.com/selleo/essential-rubyonrails-patterns-part-1-service-objects-1af9f9573ca1#:%7E:text=A%20service%20object%20is%20a,a%20wide%20area%20of%20use.&text=If%20you%20feel%20you%20might,very%20similar%20Use%20Case%20pattern.) and is extremely easy to test.

You can just pass the arguments in and write assertions about the generated CSV without having to to create a bunch of records in the database or go through the HTTP layer.

```
def index
   @users = User.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.csv do 
       send_data UsersCSVGenerator.(@users, fields: ['email']) 
     end
   end
end
```